# How to use libtool to create a dylib for iOS simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, dylib, libtool-xcode

My goal is to create a dylib using libtool. I'm on macOS, so it's **not** GNU libtool.

I tried to run `libtool -dynamic -o foo.dylib *.o -syslibroot $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk iphonesimulator)`, but got a bunch errors saying

> ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in object file (foo.o)
>   built for iOS Simulator

*(Yes, the .o file is targeted at simulator.)*

It seems by default `libtool` creates the dylib for macOS, but I couldn't find where to specify the platform. `libtool` doesn't accepct `-target` or `-platform_version`.

So, how can I use `libtool` to create a dylib for iOS simulator? Thanks!

Comment: You may want to take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39062759/798346

Comment: Thanks. I saw that question. The thing is I'm not using Xcode IDE. It's all command line tool.

Comment: No idea if it'll work, but try: `xcrun -sdk iphonesimulator libtool [rest of your flags]`